# FTP mount crash when crawling with solrj

Tags: ftp, solr

I have a lots of files in my FTP account. I use the curlftpfs to mount them to folder and then start to index them with solrj API, but after a minutes pass something strange happens and the mounted folder is not accessible and crashes. Also, I can not unmount it and the message "device is in use" appears.

My solrj code is OK and I tested it with my local files and the result is great, but indexing the mounted folder is my terrible problem.

I use the curlftpfs with CentOS, Fedora, and Ubuntu, but the result of crashing is the same. How can I fix this problem?

Is the problem with the curlftps, or did I miss some configure when mounting the folder?

Answer (score 1):

This is such an incredible hack than one should shout out: So what?

Why not use network file systems that are meant to be remote file systems? NFS comes to mind. Even CIFS. In really bad cases SSHFS. But never ever in the world I would chose FTP! In user space, ha ha!

Who pays you for doing such incredible bad things?